Questions in proving $\mathbb{P}\left(T_a<\infty\right)=1$ with $T_a:=\inf \{t>0: B_t \ge a\}$
Let $\left(B_t, t \geq 0\right)$ be a one-dimensional Brownian motion starting from the origin (i.e, $\left.B_0=0\right)$. Let $\mathcal{F}_t:=\sigma\left(B_s: s \leq t\right)$ be the filtration generated by $B_t$. For $a>0$, define $T_a:=\inf \{t>0: B_t \ge a\}$. Compute $\mathbb{E} [e^{-\lambda T_a}]$ for $\lambda>0$, and prove that $\mathbb{P}\left(T_a<\infty\right)=1$. Hint: one may consider $M_t:=e^{u B_t-u^2 t / 2}$.
The first question is direct, using the fact that $M_t$ is a martingale so $M_{t\wedge T_a}$ is also a martingale and take expectations with $u=\sqrt{2 \lambda}$ we get $\mathbb{E} [e^{-\lambda T_a}]=\exp(-a\sqrt{2\lambda})$. But now I'm having questions with the second problem. I know a quite usual way of proving $\mathbb{P}[T_a<\infty]=1$, that is using $\limsup_{t\rightarrow\infty}B_t/\sqrt{t}=\infty$ from Theorem 7.2.8 in Durrett's book. However I don't think this problem want us to solve it in this way.
If we only take derivatives on $\mathbb{E} [e^{-\lambda T_a}]=\exp(-a\sqrt{2\lambda})$ we get $\mathbb{E}[T_a]=\infty$, which is still not enouth. Is there any other ways relevant to $\mathbb{E}[e^{-\lambda T_a}]$ that can also prove $\mathbb{P}[T_a<\infty]=1$? Thank you!

Long hint (I leave the details for you): By martingale property,
$$ 1 = \mathbb{E}[M_0] = \mathbb E [M_{t\wedge T_a}] = \mathbb E \left[\exp\left( uB_{t\wedge T_a} - \frac{1}{2}u^2(t\wedge T_a)\right)\right] $$
You then send $t \rightarrow +\infty$ to get
$$  \mathbb E \left[1_{T_a < +\infty} \exp\left( ua - \frac{1}{2}u^2 T_a \right)\right] = 1 $$
or
$$ \mathbb E \left[1_{T_a < +\infty} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2}u^2 T_a \right)\right] = e^{-ua}. $$
Now send $u \rightarrow 0^+$, you get
$$ \mathbb P(T_a <+\infty) = 1. $$

Thanks, and it seems that we should prove $ \mathbb P(T_a <+\infty) = 1$ first before calculating $\mathbb{E} [e^{-\lambda T_a}]=\exp(-a\sqrt{2\lambda})$.

Yeah, it's like a byproduct
